# How to create C Source Mex File

Tags: c, matlab

I have a program in C which multiplies a scalar number with an array. I would like to create a mex file to call this function in MATLAB.
I have followed this [Link](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html), but I had some troubles with the compilation and I had to modify a part of the code.

The C function I implemented is:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void arrayProduct(double x, double *y, double *z, int n){
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        z[i]=x * y[i];
    }
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){

double multiplier;
double *inMatrix;
mwSize ncols;
double *outMatrix;

multiplier = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
#if MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX
    inMatrix=mxGetDoubles(prhs[1]);
#else
    inMatrix = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
#endif
ncols=mxGetN(prhs[1]);

plhs[0]=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,ncols,mxREAL);

#if MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX
    outMatrix=mxGetDoubles(plhs[0]);
#else
    outMatrix=mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
#endif
arrayProduct(multiplier,inMatrix,outMatrix,ncols);

if(nrhs != 2){
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nrhs","Two inputs required.");
}
if(nlhs != 1){
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nlhs","One input required.");
}
if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]) != 1){
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notScalar","Input multiplier must be scalar.");
}


if(!mxIsDouble(prhs[1]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[1])){
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notDouble","Input matrix must be type double.");
}
 
if(mxGetM(prhs[1]) != 1){
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notRowVector","Input must be a row vector.");
}
}
```

Right now, I can genereta the mex file (.mexmaci64, I use macOS) but when I call the function arrayProduct(s,A), where s=5 and A=[1.5,2,9], I receive this message:

Error using arrayProduct
One input required.

How can I fix this error to generate the correct mex file or run the function correctly?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You wrote the code but don’t know how it works? There is a test in there that checks the number of outputs (`nlhs`), and if it’s not 1, it errors out with that message you get. So, you need to call it `out = arrayProduct(s,A)`.

Comment: That said, you should really move those checks to the top of the function, before you access the data. If you check that the data is valid after reading it, it’s already too late!

Comment: @Cris I don't disagree in general - but you can assign to `plhs[0]` even when not explicitly requested, as noted here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html . In fact, it's usual to assign to `plhs[0]` even when `nlhs==0` to avoid weirdness as seen by the OP (the exception being those weird methods that have a "display stuff or return stuff" pattern).

Comment: @Edric: Yes, `plhs[0]` always exists, that test in the code is not useful (and the message it produces is wrong also). It is the checks on the input that are important to do. This code will likely crash MATLAB if called without input or with input of wrong sizes.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the problem is I call the function after mex it just like this:[B]=arrayProduct(s,A)  and I receive one error: Input must be a row vector, when I have defined s=5 and A like a row vector, A=[1.5,2,9]. So I don´t understand that error according the code I posted up.

Comment: @Edric according to the declaration of s (scalar multiplier = 5) and A (row vector = [1.5,2,9]), the function must to return the value [B] = [7.5, 10.0, 45.0]. But return the error I commented before.

Comment: That is because you use `mxGetM` to get the number of columns (which you require to be 1), but that function returns the number of rows. Please read the documentation for the functions that you use.

Comment: outMatrix=mxGetPr(prhs[0]); should be     outMatrix=mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

Comment: You should also check that prhs[1] is not sparse.  And it would be simpler for the user if you created an output the same size as the input and then used mxGetNumberOfElements to figure out how many elements to process.

Comment: The useful form of the number of outputs test is if(nlhs > 1)